# Dynamic sql in php admin

Tags: php, mysql

I'm unable to use the below statement in a stored procedure

```
set @A=(concat('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ',v_TableName,' 
                WHERE ',v_ColName,'LIKE ''%',v_NAME,'%'''));
PREPARE cnt1 from @A;
execute cnt1;
```

Comment: Why are you unable? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `'` using a `\`.

```
set @A=(concat('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ',v_TableName,
               ' WHERE ',v_ColName,' LIKE \'%',v_NAME,'%\''));
```